# Executable Jar Structure Different from Intellij Project Structure (resulting in runtime error when executing from jar)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I have an java application that I can successfully execute from intellij (where I created it). I set it up in intellij to have the standard maven structure. Below is the structure from within intellij:

[image]

However, the execution fails when running from the executable jar. It fails because the package structure created from "mvn clean package" is different from the structure in intellij. Here is the structure of the executable jar (top level):

[image]

,and here at one level below:

[image]

As you can see, its missing the src.main.java (skips right to paging_mission_control package), as well as missing the resources and test directories.

The failure is because the SensorData.txt file cannot be found at runtime (because the resources directory is missing in the jar). However, the bigger issue is that the jar file structure (as build using "mvn clean package"), is different from what is built with intellij. Intellij does not use the jar file.

Additionally, the jar file does not seem to include the pom file or the jars specified in the pom file.

I also tried "mvn clean install", but the jar is just the same as with "mvn clean package".

Update as requested by reviewers:

```
$ jar -tf paging-mission-control-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
paging_mission_control/
paging_mission_control/input/
paging_mission_control/model/
paging_mission_control/process/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/groupId/
META-INF/maven/groupId/paging-mission-control/
paging_mission_control/input/FileLoader.class
paging_mission_control/model/SatelliteConstants.class
paging_mission_control/model/SatelliteStatus.class
SensorData.txt
paging_mission_control/SatApplication.class
paging_mission_control/model/SensorReading.class
META-INF/maven/groupId/paging-mission-control/pom.properties
paging_mission_control/process/InputProcessor.class
META-INF/maven/groupId/paging-mission-control/pom.xml
```

Update as requested by reviewers (dir /s/b src):

```
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control>dir /s/b src
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\test
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\resources
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\input
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\model
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\process
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\SatApplication.java
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\input\FileLoader.java
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\model\SatelliteConstants.java
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\model\SatelliteStatus.java
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\model\SensorReading.java
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\java\paging_mission_control\process\InputProcessor.java
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\main\resources\SensorData.txt
C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control\src\test\java

C:\Users\tclotworthy\Iamus\satelliteProj\paging-mission-control>
```

I would be grateful for any ideas about how to make the executable jar work the same is the execution from intellij. Thank you

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
You'd be helping us all more if you just pasted the output of `jar -tf ThatSnapshot.jar` *formatted as code* then we can copy paste in our answers. Likewise `dir /s/b src`

Comment: @g00se, ok sorry about the images. HEre is the output:

Comment: Ah no. Just `jar -tf paging-mission-control-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` That's a `jar` command not `java`

Comment: @g00se sorry. Updated wtih correct command and output

Comment: Share your pom. Also, you don't share how you're running the jar and the error message.

Comment: Try [this](https://technojeeves.com/tech/paging-mission-control.zip) Unzip it in your home directory and look at the 'Iamus2' directory. I don't use IDEs but surely IDEA has some sort of 'Import Maven project' option. Run it and it will read resource 'SensorData.txt'. Once you've got that running, you can copy your previous classes into the packages. Dependencies will have to be adjusted in pom.xml if you have added any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is normal  behavior

It is normal behavior that JAR's folder structure is not identical to your develop environment, Since JAR is "Assembled" by build tools(in your case, maven do this), that packs the files that your application need to(classfiles, resources, dependency JARS, and the others if you configure so).

for same reason, your test files are not included in jar since they're **not required** to your application, because they only used for testing, and should not be running on your real-production environment.

All resources will be on your classpath's root, which can access from classpath using `ClassLoader`.

```java
// You should access your resource file by using absolute path
// because resource file is included in root of classpath!
InputStream fileInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourcesAsStream("SensorData.txt")
```

I don't know how you access resource, but I can say that you can check path is relative or wrong(like referencing "resource" folder).

Comment: Check also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-files.html